# Umbrella header for module 'FBLPromises' does not include header '/Headers/PromisesObjC-umbrella.h'

Tags: macos, promise, cocoapods, xcodebuild

I've been struggling with the following issue for a few days, and was hoping someone out there might have more experience with this sort of stuff.

I have a framework I'm working on [mlfairy](https://github.com/mlfairy/mlfairy) which fails cocoapod's linting for OSX specifically (it passes for iOS and tvOS).

Some things to note, my framework depends on [google-promises](https://github.com/google/promises).

Here's the error I'm getting

```
   Testing with `xcodebuild`.
 -> MLFairy (0.0.2)
    - NOTE  | [MLFairy/Core] xcodebuild:  note: Using new build system
    - NOTE  | [MLFairy/Core] xcodebuild:  note: Planning build
    - NOTE  | [MLFairy/Core] xcodebuild:  note: Constructing build description
    - WARN  | xcodebuild:  <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'FBLPromises' does not include header '/Headers/PromisesObjC-umbrella.h'
    - ERROR | [OSX] [MLFairy/Core] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.
    - NOTE  | [OSX] [MLFairy/Core] xcodebuild:  <module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
    - ERROR | [OSX] [MLFairy/Core] xcodebuild:  Target Support Files/PromisesObjC/PromisesObjC-umbrella.h:32:9: error: include of non-modular header inside framework module 'FBLPromises': '/Users/vsharma/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-bjatzrzqowzrweajjxvbfwuotulu/Build/Products/Release/PromisesObjC/FBLPromises.framework/Headers/FBLPromises.h'
    - ERROR | [OSX] [MLFairy/Core] xcodebuild:  PromisesSwift/Sources/Promises/Promise+Await.swift:15:8: error: could not build Objective-C module 'FBLPromises'
```

In order to reproduce this issue, you have to checkout the project and run the following command

```
pod spec lint --no-clean --fail-fast --verbose --allow-warnings --platforms=macos
```

Note that the workspace that's generated compiles without issues. I can't seem to isolate if the issue is related to cocoapods, google-promises, or with my framework build settings.

Comment: In case someone comes across this issue, and wants to know what's wrong, it appears that the version of Promises I'm using (1.2.8) generally fails to be included in osx projects with cocoapods. It seems that reason is because Promises uses a custom modulemap file, but is not included in the path for podspec. As of writing this, the issue is not resolved, but i did submit a PR: https://github.com/google/promises/pull/131

Comment: Deleting the GoogleUtilities directory inside the Pods directory and re-running pod install fixed the same problem for me.